# Can't remove Glassfish in windows 7 64bit

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, uninstallation

I tried to uninstall Glassfish in Windows 7 64bit, but it won't uninstall because of the following error:

> Could not find the required version of the java(tm) 2 runtime
>   environment in 'c:\glassfish3\jdk7' and this application need version
>   1.6 or higher of the java(tm) 2  runtime environment.  If the required java(tm) 2 runtime environment is not installed, you can download it
>   from  the following website: http://java.sun.com/j2se or if you
>   already have the required  java(tm) 2 runtime environment installed,
>   try rerunning ths application with the  following usage:
>   'uninstall.exe' -j

I already followed one solution for this problem but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with uninstalling Glassfish?

Comment: do you have Java 1.6 or higher installed? You can still get it to work by using the unistall command and specifying the directory, will try find the exact command

Answer (score 4):

```
uninstall.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_7\jre"
```

should uninstall Glassfish!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here it is, you can uninstall it using this command:

```
uninstall.exe -j "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

where %JAVA_HOME% can be an environment variable you set, or the absolute path that java is installed, for example:

```
uninstall.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin"
```

See if that works.

More info can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/gjxfv.html) on the oracle/sun website for Glassfish

Comment: What do you mean not working? What is the error you are getting with the above? Do you still have java installed on your computer?

Comment: i try solution above but still show error "Could not find the required version of the java(tm) 2 runtime environment in 'c:\....'". my computer have still install java

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling java? Or just installing a fresh Java?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any version's of Java installed on your machine currently. Glassfish it's self is a java installation, not a Java runtime, you cannot remove it with out having a Java runtime on your PC. I think you have probably removed Java already, but need it to get rid of glassfish. Try installing a new Java runtime, then get rid of glassfish

Comment: This is a little old, but one thing that mixed me up was that my Java installs were actually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6". Dumb oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

These didn't work for me running java 1.6.0_24 in Windows 7:

- I tried modifying the asenv.bat file that glassfish uses to find the jre to point to my jre.
- I tried manually putting it in as in C:\glassfish3\uninstall.exe -j . This was per the official Oracle documentation.

The only thing that worked was to use the original path and move the bin and lib folders from my java installation to the directory that the error dialog 
specified.  Then the Glassfish uninstall started up and completed with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
uninstall -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0"
```

Do not choose Bin-folder, that doesn't help, like `%JAVA_HOME%` (also tried).